# Slider between two full width divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I am looking for a way to have a JavaScript/jQuery function which can be used as a full page slider on a function. My HTML structure is as follows:

Now I want to do two things:

1. I want both `slide1` and `slide2` to be full width elements.
2. Furthermore, I want a function that can be called to elegantly slide from `slide1` to `slide2` and back if you call it again.

I found a solution in [`fullpage.js`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/), but that code has too much unwanted side effects (e.g., no vertical scrolling; centering of content; no smooth responsive resizing of font-size) and can do more things and therefore uses more code than I want.

I think it must be easy to accomplish in less lines, but I don't know how to go about it. I hope someone can provide me with some pointers on how to make two full-width divs (basically two "body-elements") that can be slided when calling a JavaScript/jQuery function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry too much about the number of lines. fullPage.js its only 6Kb gzipped...

And it provides compatibility with old browsers (IE 8+, Opera 12, no CSS3 browsers...), works on touch devices detecting the touch movements, provide URL anchors, and the functions you want plus many other useful ones.

You can disable the vertical centering and the resize of the text if you want. Those are optional.

Not sure what you  mean with the *vertical scrolling*, but you could use `autoScrolling:false` to accomplish something like [this](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html#secondPage), which has the horizontal slides and the normal vertical scrolling.

Comment: Hi Alvaro thanks for your answer. I think you and the other contributors made a really nice product. For my current project it does a bit too much and I am looking for a more simple solutions as possibly the other current answer.

Comment: It's fine, no worries :)

Comment: Alvaro, could you tell me how to get the content on fullpage slider pages towards the top of the screen? It is now centered.

Comment: Okay found the solution: putting `verticalCentered: false` :-).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want?

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0hx8Lcns/1/)

Simple jquery code:

```
$( "#s1" ).click(function() {
  $("#s1").css("left","-100%");
  $("#s2").css("left","0");    
});

$( "#s2" ).click(function() {
  $("#s2").css("left","100%");
  $("#s1").css("left","0");    
});
```

This slides the div with css to the left and right with a 1s transition.

Comment: It seems like my preferred solution. I will try to implement it at home.

Comment: Thanks,  but `position: absolute;` does not work with the responsive squares unfortunatey.